# Is there a way to discard any information retained in RAM without restarting when using Windows and Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-xp, windows-vista, memory

My understanding is that Truecrypt keys are retained in RAM when a device is mounted. Can I discard any information held in RAM without restarting in Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discarding data from RAM is best done by the application that owns that data.  There are mechanisms that enable a suitably privileged user to directly access RAM, but then you are left with the big problem of finding the data you want to erase and erasing it without causing an application to malfunction.  Worse yet, the data may not be in RAM: it may be in the paging file (or "swap area" in UNIX terms).  Again, sufficiently privileged users may have write access to the swap area, but you have the same big problem as before.

So I guess I'm answering your question with: Not really.

Comment: Thanks. When you say there are mechanisms, what are they? Also is there way to distinguish data held in memory to that held in paging or swap?

Comment: Under Linux, the character special file /dev/ram gives user root access to every byte of physical memory.  And the swap file or swap partition is just part of the disk, so user root can access the disk at the sector level using /dev/sda (and similar files).